# Is it safe to uninstall anacron?

Tags: cron, cron-jobs

I have my desktop system running continually without shutdown and I want to get normal times (3:01, 4:15, 5:30) for `cron.(daily|weekly|monthly)` jobs but when `anacron` is installed these jobs run at around 7:30 and there is seems to be no interval between daily/weekly/monthly jobs.

Is it safe to just remove `anacron`?

What else could be affected by change from `anacron` to regular `cron`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you don't have any additional schedules in `/etc/anacrontab` apart from daily, weekly and monthly, it should work out of the box without affecting anything except the runtimes for the daily/weekly/monthly schedules.. The default crontab checks if anacron is installed, and runs the mentioned schedules if anacron is missing from `/usr/sbin/`.

To be absolutely sure, you could do a soft removal by just stopping the anacron service with `service anacron stop` and remove `test -x /usr/sbin/anacron ||` from the lines in `/etc/crontab`. When you are satisfied, you can remove the package.

Comment: In Ubuntu 20.04, "apt remove anacron" says it will also remove ubuntu-desktop and ubuntu-desktop-minimal, which seems a bit worrisome to me.